# "Syntax error or access violation: 1064" When changing column type from string to integer [LARAVEL MIGRATION]

Tags: laravel, string, integer, database-migration, doctrine-extensions

In the down() function of my migration i have the following line:

```
 $table->integer('placeholder')->change();
```

Here I try to change the column type `'number'` from string(750 characters) to integer. Whenever I try to run this rollback, I get hit with:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax
```

This also happens when I try to change the column to something else (such as a boolean). Setting the amount of characters from 750 to 191, so: `$table->string('placeholder',191)->change();` does work.

The table I'm working in currently does not contain any data & i'm using the utf8mb4 character-set

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your column name is `number`? It is a keyword in `mysql` and such column names cannot be used unless you quote it like `` `number` ``. It is not a good practice to use such keywords as a column name.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps in the current table you have filled in the column 'placeholder' that does not correspond to the new rules of this column.

1. Create a migration with new temporary column $ table-> string
   ('temp_placeholder', 191)
2. Write a seeder to transfer data from the 'placeholder' column to 'temp_placeholder', taking into account the new specified rules for the column.
3. Create a migration to delete the 'placeholder' column and rename the 'temp_placeholder' column to 'placeholder'

Comment: Hmm, so what you are saying is that I can only alter the column by creating a new column with the new applied rules? Because the weird thing is that in my up() function I'm able to change it from string to integer with no problems

Comment: Now it is difficult to determine what the problem is. The error text says little, need to see the current table and its data in order to understand the cause of the error. Maybe what I wrote above will help.